# Making WordPress Columns Same Size

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I have been working on a WordPress site for several hours now and cannot for the life of me figure this one out. I have 4 columns in a row on my page and they are sized dependent on content. I need all 4 to be the same size. I have added a class to each of the columns and tried manually setting the height in CSS but nothing is changing. Here is the VC code of my project. Is my class of `col-height` even targeting the right place and if so, what should my CSS look like to achieve this? Thanks for any help!

```
[vc_row]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left" el_class="col_height"]
        [vc_cta h2="Handguns" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left" el_class="col_height"]
        [vc_cta h2="Bladed Objects" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left" el_class="col_height"]
        [vc_cta h2="Rifles" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left" el_class="col_height"]
        [vc_cta h2="Incendiary Devices" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More"]<p>[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
[/vc_row]
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the generated html, not the shortcodes. And include your css for the `col_height` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated this answer with the working solution. Please follow the below steps.

---

### How to set columns to equal height in Visual Composer?

**1. VC Settings**

In order to set columns within a row to be equal height, you must navigate to **Row** parameter window and check **Equal height** option to be active. All columns within this row will have equal height and align with the longest column.

[image: VC Equal Height Columns]

**Source: [WPBakery Page Builder Knowledge Base](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/wpbakery-page-builder-how-tos/how-to-set-columns-to-equal-height/)**

---

**2. VC Code inside your page**

```
[vc_row equal_height="yes" el_id="lh-custom"]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left"]
        [vc_cta h2="Handguns" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More" el_class="col_height"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left"]
        [vc_cta h2="Bladed Objects" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More" el_class="col_height"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left"]
        [vc_cta h2="Rifles" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More" el_class="col_height"]Info.[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
    [vc_column width="1/4" icons_position="left"]
        [vc_cta h2="Incendiary Devices" add_button="bottom" btn_title="Learn More" el_class="col_height"]<p>&nbsp;</p>[/vc_cta]
    [/vc_column]
[/vc_row]
```

---

**3. jQuery code inside functions.php**

```
function lh_vc_same_height_cols() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    var maxHeight = -1;

                    jQuery('#lh-custom .col_height').each(function() {
                        maxHeight = maxHeight > jQuery(this).height() ? maxHeight : jQuery(this).height();
                    });

                    jQuery('#lh-custom .col_height').each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).height(maxHeight);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'lh_vc_same_height_cols' );
```

**Source: [WPMU DEV Forum](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/css-to-make-row-items-same-height-regardless-of-screen-width#post-1135500)**

---

**Output**
[image: Equal columns output]

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked for me. There is no change between having it selected or not. Seems to be pretty common issue for people and involves particular themes.

Comment: @still2blue I have updated my answer with a working solution. Just tested it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Works on at least version [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) 6.3; unsure of how far back this specific setting goes back.

Another option using "Visual Editor" is to set the "Max Height" of a Stack Element.  Would be nice if you could do it at the "Columns" or "Column" element but its currently not capable.

---

## Editor Setting

1. Add a "Stack" Element inside the Column; I used Stack instead of List for design reasons
2. For each Columns Stack Element, Goto "Styles" -> "Min Height"
3. Set it to whichever size mode (px, %, em, rem, etc.) and then define that size's value

- Caveat: this only defines the Minimum Height, not the Maximum; so account for that in your design approach.

---

## Final Result

1. 250px Min Height
   [image]
2. 17 rem Min Height
   [image]